# postgres on k8s with glusterfs as storage

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, glusterfs

I deploy a `postgres` database on `k8s` and `glusterfs` as volume.But every time I restart my pod all of data losses.Why is that?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1       
kind: Deployment               
metadata:     
  name: postgres-deployment
  namespace: gitlab
  labels:                                                                  
    app: postgres 
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: postgres:13.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql
          name: postgres
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: gitlab
              key: postgres_username
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: gitlab
              key: postgres_password
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: gitlab
              key: postgres_db 
      volumes:
      - name: postgres
        glusterfs:
          endpoints: glusterfs-cluster
          path: gv
```

Comment: It does sound right ... Have you checked the content of /var/lib/postgresql actually holds your DB? That your volume is actually mounted, to the right place? Can you try to mount that volume from another client, while your deployment is scaled to 0 replicas, check for its data? Although it should work, any reason not to use a PersistentVolumeClaim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define PVC and PV objects. see below for reference.

```
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10GB
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    app: postgres
  name: postgres-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10GB
```

Then bind the PVC to the pod as shown below

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        ...
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          name: postgres-pv-claim
      volumes:
      - name: postgres-pv-claim
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

Comment: PVC requires dynamic provisioning, and in GFS case: heketi. Nothing in initial post would let us believe such was configured. Besides, the configuration mentioned in initial post strictly follows Kubernetes documented examples: https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/volumes/glusterfs#create-a-pod . Also, your sample mentions hostPath, which is not what was requested in the first place, and also won't work on clusters with PodSecurityPolicies enabled - would require granting extra privileges to the ServiceAccount running your Postgres Pod.

Comment: it is just a reference on how to create pv and pvc and then bind the pvc to pod definition in deployment. You need to chnage those files as per your environment.

Answer (score 0):

- As per the Kubernetes Documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#glusterfs, Unlike emptyDir, which is erased when a Pod is removed, the contents of a glusterfs volume are preserved and the volume is merely unmounted. I suggest to raise an issue at link https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/new/choose
- If you want to install GitLab with PostgresSQL Backend, it will be easier to use below Helm Charts.

https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/

https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/postgresql

https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/postgresql-ha

Answer (score -1):

### You can do this:

1.For stateful set services such as databases, StatefulSet controllers should be used to deploy;

2.The storage data resources should be of a shared type, rather than using local volumes as storage, which may be scheduled to other nodes when creating POD objects;